# Should we consider unbanning ChatGPT generated content?

Tags: discussion

So don't bite my head off, hear me out. My understanding from the discussion to ban ChatGPT was mostly centered on the fact that is was constantly wrong but sounded convincing. However, OpenAI released an update called GPT-4. According to ([1](https://forum.effectivealtruism.org/posts/eAaeeuEd4j6oJ3Ep5/gpt-4-is-out-thread-and-links), [2](https://synthedia.substack.com/p/gpt-4-is-better-than-gpt-35-here), and [3](https://becominghuman.ai/the-future-of-ai-gpt-3-vs-gpt-4-a-comparative-analysis-5ac525cb7ae1?gi=1804f9daa153)) it does a lot better in a variety of things. Here are some that may be relevant. I will write in a GPT 3.5 percentile, GPT-4 percentile, comment format. NOTE:These are approximations.

AP Physics 2:35, 60, probably good enough for most things here.

AP Statistics:40,85, definetly good enough

AP World History:65, 65, should be fine for our purposes

Let me know if am missing any other relevant metrics.

Comment: Open AI says that this model, while it may be correct at a much higher rate, still has the problem that it will just make up information sometimes: "Despite its capabilities, GPT-4 has similar limitations as earlier GPT models. Most importantly, it still is not fully reliable (it “hallucinates” facts and makes reasoning errors)." https://openai.com/research/gpt-4 I think it is still too early to open the doors to something that is *known* to actively produce misinformation. Sure, humans do too, but we have mechanisms to control for that. AI driven posts would overwhelm those mechanisms.

Comment: Yes, but it more rare. Just seeing if people think the accuracy improvements are enough to permit it. Human answers are also ossaciantly (actually more than occonsianly) wrong. The question is what level of accuracy is good enough. Also, people can also post once every 40 minutes (new users at least, who tend to be the people who dont check it over) and people posting nonsense have a way of being blocked quickly @called2voyage

Comment: Furthermore, I don't understand the drive to have AI answers here. The whole point of this site is for it to be a community knowledgebase. AI driven posts remove that aspect. I don't have a problem with someone setting up a parallel AI driven knowledgebase. It doesn't have to be here.

Comment: Where do you think this AI gets its information from? It's gets it from the internet (community knowledge). ALso, if AI posts are good enough, stack exchange could become obselete @called2voyage

Comment: I'm not concerned about where the information is from. I'm talking about the purpose of this site. It is a place for community. Someone posting AI-generated posts is not participating in that community.

Comment: I think there definetly must be guidelines (ex.You must check it and you must say you used ChatGPT) but banning something because we aren't used to it is foolish @called2voyage

Comment: I'm not advocating banning it because we're not used to it. I'm advocating having a moratorium on it until there are systems in place to control for unwanted behavior. At present, this would overwhelm community moderation.

Comment: The improvements are not related to accuracy in mathematics, or physics, or technical capability. It is a chat bot - it understands language. That is it. SO on any more technical site it has issues - better language just makes it more effort to uncover the inaccuracies. Also...potential plagiarism issue.

Comment: Agreed, this is simply a in principle is it okay. Of course there will have to be guidelines (a lot of them) to insure this goes well. This is just in terms of the quality is it okay @called2voyage

Comment: The quality is the biggest problem @Starshipisgoforlaunch - it is **not good** at anything complex. And weirdly, rocket science has complexities :-)

Comment: Yes they are, see the post. As to plagiarism issue, I agree they must be attributed to ChatGPT @RoryAlsop

Comment: I don't think we are qualified to make that call. I think this is a matter SE as a company should decide.

Comment: Okay, should this be moved to meta. @called2voyage

Comment: Attributing to ChatGPT does not solve the plagiarism issue. OpenAI says you cannot cite ChatGPT as a source, and ChatGPT itself uses sources that it does not always disclose.

Comment: You're welcome to make a post on meta. I don't want to migrate this, because I think this discussion needs to be seen here.

Comment: OpenAI is fine with copy pasting from ChatGPT @called2voyage

Comment: Yes, but they say you can't cite it as a source.

Comment: Legally, ChatGPT cannot own its information.

Comment: Currently, SE have federated some of the decisioning on this out to the sites. Probably because it may be suitable on some less technical sites. That said, a big problem even less technical sites have is folks suddenly spamming tens of posts a day using chatgpt, without even checking on existing answers - it is annoyingly high effort for mods and high rep users.

Answer (score 11):

I would say absolutely not. Problems include:

- Poor quality content when answering technical questions, which ours often are.
- Even when it gets content correct, the posts are worse than human-written ones, and have worse links, reasoning and references (ChatGPT even makes up references and data if it doesn't have definite citations)
- Mass postings by users using ChatGPT, without even checking existing answers

These massively increase the effort to moderate for all moderators and high rep users

And as @called2voyage points out, it removes the community aspect of this community

Answer (score 7):

Large Language Models like ChatGPT are not suitable for answering questions.  They literally cannot know or understand; all they can do is assemble words in statistically likely ways, like massively more complex versions of the Markov chains that preceded them.

These things are amusing, but their output shouldn't be trusted to be factual.  It's absurd and harmful that people have hooked them up to search engines, and it would be even worse to then have them feeding lies into StackExchange, which is a site that Google offers up as The Answer To Your Question for many queries (a practice that's also harmful).

No AI should be allowed until it can meaningfully participate in the site.  It should be able to offer corrections to existing answers, evaluate posts and vote constructively, and otherwise demonstrate understanding and utility.  Not get things right-enough 65% of the time and be obviously or subtly wrong for the rest of its megabytes.

[Called2Voyage's answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3037/11262) is such a wonderful demonstration of why we shouldn't allow ChatGPT or anything else that [weighs the same as a duck](https://youtu.be/yp_l5ntikaU?t=203) (i.e., anything that we might reasonably confuse for ChatGPT output:  words put together without understanding).  Not only does it (still) falsely attribute quotes to sources, but it makes up a link that looks like a credible Space Exploration StackExchange Meta question link which instead leads to a deleted answer.  And of course, in the comments on that answer, SOMEONE BELIEVES THE BOT and Called2Voyage has to explain that it's wrong!  That answer is practically *performance art* and should be showered with upvotes imo.

UPDATE:  four days later, [an answer from Starship that appears to have made up quotes from a source and pointed to a part of it that has no relevance to their answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/63157).  Coincidence?

Comment: If OpenAI claims are correct, it is correct more than 95% of the time. @Erin Anne

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch you claimed in your post that ChatGPT 4 scored a 60 on AP Physics, 85 on AP Statistics, and 65 on AP World History?  Where is the claim that they're correct more than 95% of the time?

Comment: Those are percentiles @Erin Anne

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2023/03/15/technology/gpt-4-artificial-intelligence-openai.html#:~:text=According%20to%20the%20company%2C%20GPT,beats%2099%20percent%20of%20humans). here is a source not exactly 95 but still my point

Comment: Those AP numbers are not useful in any meaningful way for the real world. And in any case, they are very very low. Even if they got to 98% co9rrect on those tests that would still be far too low to be useful here.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch if you're going to just make numbers up and then say "hey look, this source has a number, but not the number I just said," this discussion isn't going to be fruitful.  I'm cutting my losses and ignoring you now.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I agree with you 100%; I had something like that as I was drafting this, but started to get rude while saying it and took it out.  I repeated the numbers since they were the evidence given in the post and I don't want to go hunting for more, but the scores are still very bad (even if improved over GPT3) on basic tests.  Even pretending it'd do as well at posting here, which it wouldn't, it's not up to our standards for correctness.

Comment: In case anyone else has feline curiosity disorder, the closest thing i could find in the New York Times article to Starship's claim is "According to the company, GPT-4 is more capable and accurate than the original ChatGPT, and it performs astonishingly well on a variety of tests, including the Uniform Bar Exam (on which GPT-4 scores higher than 90 percent of human test-takers) and the Biology Olympiad (on which it beats 99 percent of humans)."  So nothing like the claim, unsurprisingly.

Answer (score 5):

To demonstrate why this should not be allowed yet, here is GPT-4's answer to this question:

> As an AI language model, ChatGPT is capable of generating high-quality responses to a wide range of questions on various topics, including space exploration. However, Space Exploration Stack Exchange has a strict policy against allowing automated or bot-generated content on its platform.

> In the Space Exploration Stack Exchange community guidelines, it is stated that "bots and automated scripts have the potential to cause harm to the site and its users, and are therefore not allowed." Additionally, the guidelines state that all content on the site should be written by humans and should reflect the author's expertise and experience.

> Moreover, Space Exploration Stack Exchange is primarily designed as a platform for space enthusiasts to share and discuss space exploration-related topics, and the site's moderators have the responsibility to ensure that the content meets these standards. Allowing ChatGPT-generated content could potentially dilute the quality of the platform and make it less useful for its intended audience.

> In conclusion, the policy against bot-generated content on Space Exploration Stack Exchange is in place to ensure the quality and reliability of the information provided on the platform. While ChatGPT is an impressive technology, it is not appropriate for use on Space Exploration Stack Exchange, and the ban on its use should remain in place.

> References:

> Space Exploration Stack Exchange Community Guidelines: https://space.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice
> Space Exploration Stack Exchange Meta Discussion on Bots and Automation: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/bots-on-the-site

Notice that the quote that it provides does not come from anywhere on this site, and one of the links it uses is not an actual source of the information it says.

Comment: Yes, it references our current policy, at it should. Nothing wrong there, thats something good @called2voyage

Comment: You must not have read the answer. The quote does not come from our policy, and the link is not to our policy, but to an unrelated discussion that just happens to have a title that appears related. The answer *looks* good on the surface. That's exactly the problem with ChatGPT. It's really good at producing answers that look good, but they're riddled with technical problems.

Comment: "In the Space Exploration Stack Exchange community guidelines, it is stated that "bots and automated scripts have the potential to cause harm to the site and its users, and are therefore not allowed." Additionally, the guidelines state that all content on the site should be written by humans and should reflect the author's expertise and experience." @called2voyage

Comment: Yes, that quote is not found on this site. It expresses a similar sentiment but that quote is not here.

Comment: Just to further demonstrate the problem. I asked ChatGPT again, and now it says this:
"As an AI language model, ChatGPT is programmed to generate responses to queries based on its training data, which includes a vast amount of information on various topics, including space exploration. Therefore, ChatGPT can provide insightful and informative answers to questions related to space exploration, just like any human expert in the field."

Comment: Okay, but it gets the point across. That is what matters. Frankly, we dont like when people just copy paste from sources @called2voyage

Comment: Did you give the exact same prompt @called2voyage if so then i would agree that this supportes you

Comment: You're totally misunderstanding the problem here. ChatGPT tells you what you want to think. You can get contradictory information from it

Comment: That is why you ask it neutral questions. Yes, ChatGPT is only as good as its input @called2voyage

Comment: No, it's not even as good as its input. It will produce *fake* information regardless.

Comment: It may accidentally be right, but it can't even prove that it is right.

Comment: It will almost never produce fake information with the correct input. Just like a human may have a hard time proving "common sense" ChatGPT will have a hard time proving things too @called2voyage already, people ask ChatGPT instead of here

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch - no, it actively produces fake information, without even being asked. Just look at the number of papers folks have asked it to write - look convincing until you try to find the citations. Many utterly made up. It just knows how to string words together convincingly. It knows nothing of science or maths or anything except language.

Comment: That was gpt-3 @RoryAlsop

Comment: GPT-4 does the same thing. I've tested it myself.

Comment: Weird, I just noticed that the second link is redirecting to https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/890/do-i-stack-imgur-com-pngs-and-gifs-ever-expire/1185#1185.  I'm not surprised that GPT4 got it wrong, but I didn't realize that the 1185 is basically the only important part to the site.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch - it is still not anything other than a language based algorithmic tool. So assuming v4 will suddenly make it able to understand technical subjects is just wrong - it is not made to do that.